# How many entrances did most European castles have?

Tags: medieval

Other than the obvious main gatehouse and watergate (if built near water), were there any other entrances or exits to European castles?  Were there commonly found secret escape tunnels, entrances for service workers, or other lesser-known access points?  I'm looking to find a few more creative ways to get a character into a castle.  It would be a well-fortifitied castle with an outer curtain wall, moat, etc.  Not during a siege but during uncertain times.

Comment: Kinda need a bit more information on the castle. Can't plan a heist if we don't even know the building and a basic sense of where it is. There is a big difference sneaking into a wartime alert castle keep studded with towers built on a tall bluff with a huge moat versus an upgraded manor house with a small curtain wall in the countryside.

Comment: Who is the attacker: a rival lord? A thief? A spy? An attacking army? Rioters?

Comment: Better setting of the stage for this situation would likely help both the OP and us come up with a more useful answer to what is effectively:
"What are some unique or uncommon ways a character could sneak into a castle?"

If however this is the actual question it should be clearly stated as such.

Comment: I suggest wandering around a physical castle if you can. Once you do, you'll realize how small they often are, how thick the walls are, how solid the ground is etc.How castles were in my head did not match up to reality when I got to Europe and saw some.

Comment: If it's not wartime, you might disguise yourself as a servant, or hide under a cart delivering produce to the castle.

Comment: Wasn't this the plot of a Bugs Bunny cartoon?

Comment: There are as as many entrances as your plot requires .If you need to name them, it can be a secret tunnel (overdone), or a sally port (which would be sealed unless needed, so someone on the inside would need to open it)

Comment: this sounds like a history question. but the answer will be the same it depends on the type of castle and location. some castles had many entrances some only one. "castle" covers everything from a fortified city to a single keep.

Comment: This belongs on: https://history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact -- Hopefully the edited / rewritten question clarifies the heist issue! I read this now as a "finite list of things" sort of question the answer to which would be used to design fortified positions within the OP's world!

Comment: @elemtilas I'm with you on this one. The rewritten question has a superior focus. Hopefully someone will remember the holes for the potties....

Comment: I would like to underscore what @sdfgeoff said, though. I toured a number of medieval castles in Finland - and he's right. They're not at all what you grow up imagining. They're small, with cramped rooms and small hallways built on incredibly solid ground in areas intentionally selected to be easily defended. Every opening literally defeated the purpose of the castle. In reality, there might only ever be a max of two entrances: the main gate and, if located by a large water source, a boat gate. Your imagination might be worth more than reality.

Answer (score 1):

- [Sally port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_port):
  A sufficiency large castle might have a door to let a small group of defenders out. To small for supplies, etc., and well positioned for counterattack.
- [Postern gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postern):
  More generally, a small secondary gate. This could include sally ports.
- [Bridge Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germans%27_Gate):
  A castle combined with a toll bridge.

Answer (score 0):

**How many entrances did most European castles have?**

There really is no single answer to this, it depends on the castle, who designed it, what for, how big a castle it is etc, no two castles are the same (well not many of them) so just pick a castle of suitable size & type for your purpose & use the number it has or make it up yourself.

Though obviously a working defensive castle should have as few as possible.

Here's an example castle for you [Bodiam Castle](https://www.google.com/search?q=bodiam%20castle%20&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj8pdiskrPyAhUCwIUKHbU4DlIQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=bodiam%20castle%20&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQDDIECAAQQzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABFCujRVYro0VYLicFWgAcAB4AIABXIgBXJIBATGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=8RcZYbzpE4KAlwS18biQBQ&bih=760&biw=1536&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB919GB919)

It has a single entrance now but [a search for maps for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=bodiam%20castle%20map&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwioj6XTk7PyAhWC_IUKHdJzAqsQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=bodiam%20castle%20map&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQ6BggAEAgQHjoECAAQGFDRkRVYrJsVYLumFWgAcAB4AIABrAGIAZsDkgEDMy4xmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=ThkZYaiwK4L5lwTS54nYCg&bih=760&biw=1536&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB919GB919) shows it originally had two.

*Irrelevant sidebar: those trees around the moat wouldn't be there if it was in active use as a medieval fortification, they'd be cover & handy siege material for any attackers so wouldn't be allowed to grow.*